# running a bash script on zsh won't source the environment variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have the following bash script. It is actually an env variable file that contains some environment variables I want to set depending on an argument I pass in when I source it. Here is a MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# CONSTANTS
PROD_STR='prod'
TEST_STR='test'

# Set the environment: 'prod' or 'test'
if [ "$1" == $PROD_STR ] || [ "$1" == $TEST_STR ]; then
    export DEV_ENV=$1
    echo "Found valid dev environment: "$DEV_ENV
else
    echo "No valid environment specified"
    echo "Usage: env_vars <env>"
    echo '       env - one of "prod" or "test"'
fi  

case $DEV_ENV in
    $PROD_STR)
        export MY_HOST='fooProd.net'
        export PORT='8000';;
    $TEST_STR)
        export MY_HOST='fooTest.net'
        export PORT='8100';;
esac

export API_USERNAME='foo'
export API_PASSWORD='mypwrd'
```

Now I wanted to `source` this file which I have named `test_env_var.sh`. I tried.

1. `source test_env_var.sh prod`
   It gives me the following `test_env_var.sh:8: = not found`
2. `. ./test_env_var.sh prod`.
   It still gives me: `./test_env_var:8: = not found`.
3. `./test_env_var prod`
   It now runs without errors and echoes (as it should) the output
   `Found valid dev environment: prod`.

So now after doing (3) I would expect to see my env variables set. But when I do

```
echo $API_USERNAME
```

It doesn't return anything.

**Workaround**

I temporarily change my $SHELL into bash by typing `bash` on the prompt. Then I run the script as

```
. test_env_var prod
```

and now when I try to `echo` any `env variable` I have set (for example `echo $API_USERNAME` it returns me `foo` as it should ). Even if I change back to `zsh` by typing `zsh` the environment variables are still there.

**Question:**
Why is this happening?. Is there no way for me to run this bash script without changing the $SHELL to bash?. Perhaps the syntax of the bash script needs to change so that it runs on `zsh`. But that's not an option since this file is under version control.

**Some more context**
Both my `zsh` and `bash` are `usr/local/bin/` so the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` should take care of this, I would think.

Comment: Replace `[ "$1" == $PROD_STR ] || [ "$1" == $TEST_STR ]` with `[[ "$1" == $PROD_STR ]] || [[ "$1" == $TEST_STR ]];`. This will work both in bash and zsh. Realize however, that sourcing a bash script in zsh, will execute every line in that script as if zsh. The shebang only has an effect when executing the script and not sourcing it. Sourcing scripts is as if you copy-pasted the script in the terminal or the parent script (with updated arguments `$1`, `$2`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if [ "$1" == $PROD_STR ] || [ "$1" == $TEST_STR ]; then
```

to

```
if [ "$1" = $PROD_STR ] || [ "$1" = $TEST_STR ]; then
```

`==` is a `bash` extension. `=` is the standard POSIX syntax, which is supported by both `bash` and `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your confusion regarding

> Even if I change back to zsh by typing zsh the environment variables are still there.

You're essentially nesting shell sessions inside each other, so if you execute `exit` twice, you go back to your initial shell.

ex:

```bash
zsh> bash
bash> zsh
zsh>

zsh> exit
bash> exit
zsh>
```